# Change Snow Leopard Login Wallpaper w/ Terminal

Tags: snow-leopard, terminal, login

I know this is possible as I did it once before.

How do you set the login background wallpaper to something else using terminal?

Answer (score 2):

The login screen background image is located at `/System/Library/CoreServices/DefaultDesktop.jpg` — you can simply `sudo cp` another jpeg image to replace it (though I'd recommend backing it up first!).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder"
     set desktop picture to POSIX file "/path/to/file.jpg"
end tell
```

It should be fairly easy to package this in an Automator script.

Alternatively, you can use `defaults`:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktop Background '{default = {ImageFilePath = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Black & White/Lightning.jpg"; };}'
```

I haven't tested this myself, so you may have to run `killall Dock` before this takes effect.

Edit: [more information on this and launchd](http://thingsthatwork.net/index.php/2008/02/07/fun-with-os-x-defaults-and-launchd/)

Comment: The question is now to change the login wallpaper, not the desktop wallpaper.  The script you provided only works for the desktop background.